# React Native Installation Issue

Tags: ios, react-native, performance, mobile

when I try to install the react native in my new mac this happens tried many solutons but ended up with nothing

`✔ Downloading template ✔ Copying template ✔ Processing template ✖ Installing Ruby Gems error /Users/sandeepkumar.y/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:277:in` find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from /Users/sandeepkumar.y/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:296:in `activate_bin_path' from /Users/sandeepkumar.y/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/bin/bundle:23:in` '
✖ Installing Ruby Gems
error Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=macos&platform=android and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.`

How can I solve this issue

Comment: Can you let me know the command